# Inserting large number of records into SQL Server

Tags: batch-file, sql-server-2014, multiple-records

I have a very large number of records that must be inserted into a SQL Server database. It is about 1 million record that must be inserted.

I do so by running this simple bat script:

```
ECHO %TIME%
sqlcmd -S "SQLSERVER" -i "C:\Users\name\Desktop\OutPut\Result 
tblAccount.sql"
ECHO %TIME%
Pause
```

But once I run the script I get the following error:

> some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries

Is there any solution to how to insert that many records?

I have SQL Server 2014 Developer edition.

Edit the question by adding the query I'm running

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblAccount] 
               WHERE [AccountID] = 117242 
                 AND [TimeStamp] = CAST(N'2013-01-16 05:53:50.490' AS DateTime)) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblAccount] ([AccountID], [Name], [Comment],[IsMachine],
                                    [UserID], [Prefix], [Action], [Initials],
                                    [Name], [TimeStamp], [Reason], [Iscal]) 
    VALUES (117242, 'blabla', 'The users project)', 1, 
            'val', 39, 'val', 'blabla',
            'blabla', CAST(N'2013-01-16 05:53:50.490' AS DateTime), 'NORMAL', '0')
END
```

Comment: The error has little to do with the number of records you're trying to insert but related to the INSERT query in the tblAccount.sql script.  If you don't share that along with explanations then we can't help

Comment: I must disagree with you, as the script runs fine when I run it with small amount of records. but it fails with all records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is related to a bug in 2012 (fixed in SP2) and 2014 (fixed in SP1) according to this connect item, 
https://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver/feedback/details/805659/sql-statement-is-nested-too-deeply -

Comment: That did not help at all. I did install the Service pack 1 and after that SP2  as suggested but it did not help at all. I still get the same error, nothing has changed. I will keep looking into other solutions/workarounds